# Spring static resources mapping : controller vs addResourceHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to map a particular set of resources(audio) to a controller. But resources/** maps to all resources. How can I isolate a particular resource request so that it doesnt go through the Spring static resources mapping, but to my controller? Is moving the audio resources to a different folder other than resources the only solution?

For example:

Folder structure:

```
/resources/js
/resources/css
/resources/audio
```

Resources Mapping using Spring Web Config:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
{
   registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
...
}
```

Resources Controller:

```
public class ResourceController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/resources/audio",  
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Resource getAudio(...) {
    }
   ....
```

}

Answer (score 2):

> Is moving the audio resources to a different folder other than
>   resources the only solution?

Whats the problem with that ? Seems perfect : conventional and intuitive to me. If its not a static don't do make it static.

Comment: Before posting this, I was under the impression there would be a conflict between the Controller and the resource handlers, since both of them have the same request mapping resources/<something>. After testing I see there is no conflict. But generally what is the principle here, should it be moved outside the resource handler mapping, since its being handled by the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to specify exclusion in ant path. And I think many utilities based on ant path matching provide both an include and a exclude path for that reason.

But anyway, it would be dangerous in the sense of future evolutions to have under `/resources` data that will be served by a controller, as NimChimpsky also said.